# What makes an anime a classic?

Tags: anime-production

I remember when one of Hayao Miyazaki's films came out, it was considered a new classic. What makes the anime a new classic.

Comment: +1- Probably originality and an anime that you'll remember fifty years later and have a nostalgic flashback of.

Comment: Who is the body that considers it a classic, the general public or like 'classic anime' dvd releases? The first is definitely more subjective

Answer (score 0):

... Is this regarding Howl's Moving Castle?

It was based on a classic fantasy novel (by Diana Wynne Jones) so maybe some people were actually referring it to a new take on a classic, or it was classic in the sense that people knew it was going to be a classic because the quality of that film was on that tier. Kind of like how in the same way Disney movies turn out to be classics even when a new film comes out because of it's rich history in making classic animated movies.

Comment: @Velda- I think she is asking what makes an anime a classic rather than what is a classic.